# PowerShell - Setting a Data Row column type to a custom object

Tags: api, powershell, datatable, pscustomobject

I consider myself fairly new to scripting in PowerShell and I am currently having issues assigning the return value of an API request to a Data Row.

The returned value appears to be a custom object: `<APITenant>.FRSHEATServiceReqTemplateParam` and if I try to assign this to the data table, it simply displays the object name rather than the values e.g.

```
Name                                 Params                                   
----                                 ------                                   
Access to Mailbox/Distribution Group OscarStg.FRSHEATServiceReqTemplateParam[]
```

```
strSubscriptionRecId : 0221877CF3474492B8ACD9F7C0D94E4A
strDateSubscribed    : 10/6/2017 8:09:58 AM
strOrgUnitId         : 37393D7C9B554ACEB1F2F2505BA1FF6D
strName              : Access to Mailbox/Distribution Group
strItem              : 
strDescription       : Request for access to be added or removed from a 
                       mailbox/group.
strServiceName       : Email Messaging Service
strRecId             : 21BB52854D524958A5C9F9E0DCAB60CB
lstParameters        : {eacc_dpmnt, eacc_req, eacc_reqEmail, eacc_item...}
```

Can I assign the actual value to the data table?

EDIT:

```
$cboTmpl.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $tmplRecId = $cboTmpl.SelectedItem["RecId"]
    $index = $dTblTmpl.RecId.IndexOf($cboTmpl.SelectedValue)
    If($dTblTmpl.Rows[$index].SubId.GetTypeCode() -eq 'DBNull'){
        $tmpSubName = $dTblTmpl.Rows[$index].Name.Replace("&", "&amp;")
        $dTblTmpl.Rows[$index].SubId = ($Oscar.GetSubscriptionId($connect.sessionKey, `
        $txtTenant.Text, $tmpSubName)).subscriptionId
    }
    If($dTblTmpl.Rows[$index].Params.GetTypeCode() -eq 'DBNull'){
        $currParams = ($Oscar.GetPackageData($connect.sessionKey, $txtTenant.Text, $dTblTmpl.Rows[$index].SubId)).srSubscription.lstParameters
        $dTblTmpl.Rows[$index].Params = $currParams
    }
})
```

The last if block calls the method and assigns this to the data table. I tried to use -ExpandProperty but it similarly assigns the string 'System.Object[]' as the value.

Do I need to explicitly define the column object?

Comment: Could you show your code. -ExpandProperty may be the answer depending on what else you are doing.

Comment: @EBGreen Thanks for your comment - please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working - I had to explicitly define the column as the base type of the object. In this case, `[System.Array]`.

```
New-Variable -Name "$('col' + $Header)" -Value (New-Object `
        System.Data.DataColumn $Header,([System.Array])) -Force}
```

Now it returns the proper value.

```
$dTblTmpl.Rows[2] | select Name, Params

Name           Params
----           ------
[TEST] Request {chk, qty}
```